# How to create customized web domains?

Tags: url, dns

For example, straight from Stack Overflow:

> http://winterba.sh/

What's with that? I've seen it before and always wondered how it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special here...instead of using the top level domain `.com` (as in stackoverflow **.com**), they are using the top level domain `.sh`.

That's all. As long as the word that you want as a domain ends with the letters of some existing top level domain, you can use a domain like this.

Answer (score 2):

.sh is the Saint Helena domain suffix. Similar to .us for the US.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.sh

Comment: Haha, thanks. The things we do for points that *really* matter. :)

Comment: Oh, all they're doing is picking an existing country's domain that fits their need? Neat.

Comment: Yep, that's correct. You can see an example of some other creative uses for "non-conventional" domain names here -> http://www.pcdrome.com/most-popular-creative-domain-name-ideas-strategies/1424